# Two-parameter Lie transformation from two one-parameter Lie transformations

Tags: lie-groups, transformation

Define one-parameter Lie transformation which takes values $\Psi(\varepsilon, x)$ to be a transformation which satisfies the following properties, where $\varepsilon \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $x$ is in some suitable space to make it well-defined.

$$ \Psi(\varepsilon_1, \Psi(\varepsilon_2,x)) = \Psi(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2, x) $$
$$ \Psi(0,x) = x $$

My question is whenever you have two such transformations, is it possible to create a two-parameter Lie transformation defined by the following properties, and so that two initial one-parameter Lie transformations are somehow included in the two-parameter transformation (for example, by taking $\Theta(\varepsilon,0,x)$ or $\Theta(0,\delta,x)$)?

$$ \Theta(\varepsilon_1, \delta_1, \Theta(\varepsilon_2, \delta_2, x)) = \Theta(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2, \delta_1+\delta_2, x) $$
$$ \Theta(0,0,x) = x $$

Intuitively, I think it should be true as, for example, for groups, it is easy to define group on Cartesian product by $(g,h) \cdot_{G \times H} (g',h') = (g\cdot_{G}g', h\cdot_H h')$, but I do not see how this translates here. I also think that intuition for wanting this two-parameter group is to define transformation such that if we start from some $x$ then all $y$ that can be reached by finite applications of two one-parameter Lie transformations is the same set as all $y$ that can be reached by newly defined two-parameter transformation.

If possible, can you please provide example construction for $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ where two one-parameter Lie groups are translation and rotation, as given next?

$$ \Psi_1(\varepsilon, x) = (x_1 + \varepsilon, x_2, x_3)$$
$$ \Psi_2(\varepsilon, x) = (x_1 \cos \varepsilon + x_2 \sin \varepsilon, -x_1 \sin \varepsilon + x_2 \cos \varepsilon, x_3) $$

**EDIT**: It seems that this example is not sufficiently interesting, as I believe it was worked out by user @Cosmas Zachos, and so I provide another one in hope to make it more interesting. These are just two rotations about different axes.

$$ \Psi_1(\varepsilon, x) = (x_1 \cos \varepsilon + x_3 \sin \varepsilon, x_2, -x_1 \sin \varepsilon + x_3 \cos \varepsilon)$$
$$ \Psi_2(\varepsilon, x) = (x_1 \cos \varepsilon + x_2 \sin \varepsilon, -x_1 \sin \varepsilon + x_2 \cos \varepsilon, x_3) $$

Comment: Are you asking whether, given the representations of two Lie group on some set, there exists a representation on the same set of some group which contains the original two as a subgroup?

Comment: @RichardMyers I am not sure if this is equivalent to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't appreciate what you are asking. If you are asking for a simple representation or realization of your three maps, it is evident by inspection that
$$
\Psi(\epsilon, x)= x+\epsilon, \\
\Theta (\epsilon, \delta, (x_1,x_2))= (x_1+\epsilon,x_2+\delta),
$$
1d and 2d translations; and, lastly,
$$
\Psi_1(\epsilon,(x_1,x_2)) =(x_1+\epsilon, x_2) ,\\
\Psi_2( \epsilon, (x_1,x_2))=    \begin{pmatrix}
      \cos \epsilon &\sin\epsilon \\
      -\sin \epsilon &\cos\epsilon
    \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
       x_1\\
     x_2
    \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1 \cos \epsilon +x_2 \sin\epsilon \\
     -x_1  \sin\epsilon +x_2   \cos \epsilon
    \end{pmatrix},   
$$
1d translation and 2d rotation respectively. I skipped $x_3$, as it is a superfluous inert parameter here, and need not be written down explicitly.

---

*Response to EDIT in question*.  This it a composition of two rotations, a latitude and a longitude,
$$
\Psi_1( \epsilon, (x_1,x_2,x_3))=    \begin{pmatrix}
      \cos \epsilon &0&\sin\epsilon \\ 0&1&0 \\
      -\sin \epsilon &0&\cos\epsilon \\
 \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
       x_1\\
     x_2\\ x_3
    \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1 \cos \epsilon +x_3 \sin\epsilon \\ x_2 \\
     -x_1  \sin\epsilon +x_3   \cos \epsilon\\ 
    \end{pmatrix},  \\
\Psi_2( \delta, (x_1,x_2,x_3))=    \begin{pmatrix}
      \cos \delta   &\sin \delta &0\\
      -\sin  \delta &\cos \delta &0\\
0&0& 1
    \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
       x_1\\
     x_2\\ x_3
    \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix}
      x_1 \cos \delta  +x_2 \sin\delta   \\
     -x_1  \sin\delta   +x_2   \cos\delta  \\x_3
    \end{pmatrix},   
$$
***non-commuting*** rotations about the y and z axes, respectively, so ε is an altitude angle an δ an azimuth.

You may always consider $\Psi_1(\epsilon, \Psi_2(\delta,\vec x  ))\equiv \Theta(\epsilon,\delta, \vec x)$, via matrix multiplication of the above two matrices, to get a *general* rotation matrix, as you learned in college mechanics.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! Sorry, I am not sure what does "language homework" mean. I probably did not ask my question clearly enough. I am asking if one can always (and if yes, how) find function $\Theta$ so that it satisfies group properties with respect to both $\varepsilon, \delta$ and image of $\Theta$ for fixed $x$ is exactly the same as set of points obtained by finite combinations of $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$. It seems that your $\Theta$ satisfies these properties for my given functions $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$. How did you find this $\Theta$? Also, please see my edit.

Comment: I'm still confused about what your plain rotations at the end have to do with the translations in Θ... Your edit has trivial rotations around the $x_2$ and $x_3$ axes respectively; will write up next.

Comment: Wait, sorry, you wrote down definitions of $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ but did not give a construction of $\Theta$. Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ you can use finite combinations of $\Psi_1, \Psi_2$ to obtain new points, and I believe set of those points is exactly set of all $y$ with $|y| = |x|$. Is there a $\Theta$ which is a function of parameters $\varepsilon, \delta$ such that $\Theta$ satisfied group properties and set of all values of $\Theta$ for fixed $x$ is exactly set of all $y$ with $|y| = |x|$?

Comment: I really, really, don't understand your idiosyncratic language. Are you comfortable with the [rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) ? You want different parameters for $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$, respectively?

Comment: I am certainly not an expert on the rotation group, but I think for the purpose of my question, it is not necessary. I don't understand your comment as each $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ has only one (group) parameter $\varepsilon$.